# What will the US send to Mars as mentioned in this statement to the press?

Tags: mars, nasa

The video [U.S. planning to send 'something beautiful' to Mars, praises SpaceX](https://youtu.be/yAAsyxXBQi4) shows a statement made to the press yesterday. I've included a transcription based on the closed captions in the video, with minor edits and punctuation where viable.

Near the end, the speaker says "...we’re bringing that whole spaceflight back. We’ll be sending something very beautiful to Mars in the very near future and we’re going to areas that nobody thought possible certainly not this quickly."

What might that beautiful thing be, and what are the areas that nobody thought possible?

> Before me are some rocket ships.
>
> You haven’t seen that for this country in a long time, and many of the jobs we’re doing and Mike Pence is the Chairman. Many of these jobs we’re doing are privately financed. We’re letting them use the Kennedy Space Center for a fee, and you know rich guys they love rocket ships and that’s good, that’s better than us paying for them.
>
> And I noticed the prices of the last one that they said it cost eighty million dollars. If the government did it the same thing would have cost probably forty, fifty times that amount of money. I mean literally when I heard eighty million you know I’m so used to hearing different numbers with NASA, but NASA’s making tremendous strides and we’re using a lot of private money a lot of people that love they love rockets and they’re rich so they’re gonna be a little less rich probably but a lot of rockets are going up and we’re really at the forefront, nobody’s doing what we’re doing.
>
> I don’t know if you saw last with Elon with the the rocket boosters where they’re coming back down. To me that was more amazing than watching the rocket go up, because I’ve never seen that before - nobody’s seen that before - where they’re saving the boosters and they came back without wings, without anything. They landed so beautifully. So we’re really at the forefront and we’re doing it in a really private manner.
>
> At the same time NASA is very much involved in doing their own projects, but we’re bringing that whole spaceflight back. We’ll be sending something very beautiful to Mars in the very near future and we’re going to areas that nobody thought possible certainly not this quickly. So we’re very proud.
>
> So they had these outside, in fact they were sort-of spread much further apart. I said let’s bring them a little closer so the cameras can see it. But it’s really amazing what’s happening with regard to space and our country.
>
> Thank you all very much. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds to me like the "something beautiful" is just rhetoric. He's not referring to anything in specific, basically just saying that we will send something, and whatever it will be, it will be "beautiful".

Comment: I mean decrypting Trump's speech is a pretty tough job but I'd wager he's talking about the insight lander as that's going to Mars very very soon. He probably got briefed on it and forgot exactly what it's called.

Comment: @Dragongeek that sounds like a logical conclusion, I think you are probably right. If you can estimate what might be happening, it seems to be reasonable to post as an answer.

Comment: That Mike Pence "critical space hardware, do not touch"?

Comment: There's a "primarily opinion-based" close vote. Considering that there is an accepted and well received fact-based answer drawn from NASA's schedule; it's hard to see how "primarily opinion-based" applies here. Would the close-voter consider leaving a comment? If the concern is about the now-deleted answer, *protecting the question* is a better way to go than closing it.

Comment: @Dragongeek It's plausible that he forgets about a lander named after something he cannot relate to ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the "beats" this speech hits per paragraph, I'd say that Trump is talking about the InSight Lander as this section is clearly about NASA, whereas the previous section was about private spaceflight (SpaceX). InSight matches the description (notably the very soon part) and the surrounding context is about NASA so the only Mars missions that really come into consideration are InSight and Mars 2020--one of which is still a while off.

Comment: Excellent "deciphering". InSignt will indeed be beautiful, since of course all spacecraft are in their own ways.